# Install icon not visible for PWA

Tags: installation, progressive-web-apps

I have the following folder structure:

```
root
- index.html
- app.html
- worker.js
- img
- script
  - app.js
  - etc.
- style
- etc.
```

The service worker is registered in `script/app.js`.

The manifest contains all the necessary fields. Relevant part:

```
...
"start_url": "./app.html",
...
```

Lighthouse reports `Web app manifest and service worker meet the installability requirements` for both `index.html` and `app.html`, but also reports `Does not register a service worker that controls page and start_url` for `index.html`.

If I open `index.html` (either from localhost via XAMPP or from the remote server) in Chrome on desktop, the install button in the address bar is visible, and I can install the PWA.

However, if I open `index.html` in Samsung Internet on Android (Galaxy phone), the install icon is not visible, only if I navigate to `app.html`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your icon square eg 192x192. IIRC that was an issue on some browsers

Comment: @McMurphy I am talking about the icon in the right side of the address bar of the browser.